# Question on simple modules and vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $F$ be a field and let $R = F[x]$.

1. If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space and $f:V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map, then explain how to make $V$ into a left $R$-module via $x\cdot v = f(x)$ for any $v \in V$.
2. Let $F$ be algebraically closed. A left $R$-module $V$ is called *simple* if the only submodules are {0} and $V$. Show that if $V$ has dimension 2 or more, then it cannot be simple.
3. Let $F = \mathbb{R}$ and let $V$ be a 2-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Give an explicit $f:V \rightarrow V$ such that $V_f$ is a simple $R$-module. This shows being algebraically closed in the previous part of the problem is required.

I got (1) done.

For (2) I know that the submodules of $V$ correspond to the $f$-stable subspaces of $V$ i.e. $W \subseteq V$ such that $f(W) \subseteq W$. Would the Rank-Nullity theorem somehow be applicable here?

I'm not sure how to go about starting (3).

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this correct? $x⋅v=f(x)$ since x is an unknown.

Comment: There is no $f$ given in (2). However, you can set $f(v) := x\cdot v$ to see that $V$ is indeed given as in (1), where it should have been $x\cdot v := f(v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (2), let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $f$ (it must exist, since $F$ is algebraically closed) and consider the subspace $Fv$. It's a submodule, distinct from $\{0\}$ and from $V$, and therefore $V$ is not simple.

For (3), consider$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(-y,x).\end{array}$$If it had a submodule distinct from $\{0\}$ and from $V$, it would be $1$-dimensional, and therefore it would be an eigenspace. But $f$ has no real eigenvalues.